# notify change in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have created a SQLite DB (which I am trying to use as contentProvider) and need your help to guide me on this:

1) Register a content observer (I don't know how to create URI for my Database)

2) on DB changes like update/delete row, I want to notify the contentObserver which has registered to URI of DB .

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend the ContentProvider class to implement your content provider.

The Android documentation walks you through the necessary steps including how to signal ContentObservers:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html